# Problem with timestamps in governance platform

Tags: ink, rust, timestamp

I have governance platform written in ink!, where I can create poll with pollId, number of options, and with `poll_start_time` and `poll_end_time`. And this is fine.

So when poll is started I can't call vote function, and revert an error `PollIsNotStarted`.

Create poll function:

```
#[ink(message)]
        pub fn create_poll(
            &mut self,
            poll_id: String,
            number_of_options: u32,
            poll_start_timestamp: Timestamp,
            poll_end_timestamp: Timestamp,
        ) -> Result<(), Error> {

            let current_timestamp = self.env().block_timestamp();
            let poll_info = self.poll_data.get(&poll_id).unwrap_or_default();

            if poll_info.number_of_options != 0 {
                return Err(Error::PollIdAlreadyExists);
            }
            
            if number_of_options < 2 {
                return Err(Error::InvalidNumberOfOption)
            }

            if poll_start_timestamp < current_timestamp {
                return Err(Error::InvalidStartTimestamp)
            }

            if poll_end_timestamp <= poll_start_timestamp {
                return Err(Error::InvalidEndTimestamp)
            }

            let poll_info = PollInfo {
                number_of_options,
                poll_start_timestamp,
                poll_end_timestamp,
            };

            self.poll_data.insert(&poll_id, &poll_info);

            self.env().emit_event(PollCreated {
                poll_id: poll_id.clone(),
                number_of_options,
                poll_start_timestamp,
                poll_end_timestamp,
            });

            Ok(())
        }
```

Vote function:

```
#[ink(message)]
        pub fn vote(
            &mut self,
            poll_id: String,
            voting_option: u32,
            number_of_votes: Balance,
        ) -> Result<(), Error>{
            let caller = self.env().caller();

            if number_of_votes <= 0 {
                return Err(Error::InvalidNumberOfVotes)
            }

            let poll_info = self.poll_data.get(&poll_id).unwrap_or_default();
            let current_timestamp = self.env().block_timestamp();       

            if current_timestamp < poll_info.poll_start_timestamp {
                return Err(Error::PollIsNotStarted)
            }

            if current_timestamp > poll_info.poll_end_timestamp {
                return Err(Error::PollIsFinished);
            }
    
            if voting_option > poll_info.number_of_options{
                return Err(Error::InvalidNumberOfOption)
            }

            let mut voting_info = self.voting.get(&(poll_id.clone(), caller)).unwrap_or_default();

            if voting_info.voting_option == 0 {
                voting_info.voting_option = voting_option;                
            } else {
                if voting_info.voting_option != voting_option {
                    return Err(Error::VoteDenied)
                }
            }

            voting_info.number_of_votes += number_of_votes;    
                
            self.voting.insert(&(poll_id.clone(), caller), &voting_info); 

            self.env().emit_event(Voted {
                poll_id: poll_id.clone(),
                voter: caller,
                voting_option,
                number_of_votes,
            });           

            Ok(().into())


        }
```

I think this is about Timestamps, I am not sure. When I erase timestamps in vote function, it works fine. Where I am wrong?

Comment: Just confirm, you created a poll first before the vote function correct? Maybe you can share your test case code.

Comment: Yes, I do create a poll first. Do you think the problem is in tests? I didn't yet wrote the test code.

Comment: while `create_poll` what time did you select? May be that time doesn't meet and that's why it's give `PollIsNotStarted`

Comment: I select time in the future as a start time, and let's say 2 minutes after start time as a poll end time. And when poll is finished I still got same error that the `PollIsNotStarted`

Comment: I tried everything here, and I had something, when I create a poll and when poll is started I can't vote until I create second poll, and than I can vote for the first poll I create (when poll is started). Do anyone have a clue what is going on?

Comment: Are you using seconds or miliseconds for the timestamp?

Comment: Timestamp in ink! is in miliseconds.

Comment: Try to debug the contract by using `ink::env::debug_println!(<time>)` in the constructor and in the message to determine what's happening with the time

Comment: Problem is in start time, when I erase that IF with `PollIsNotStarted`, works normally, poll is ending on time, and I can withdraw funds. @GermanNikolishin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, problem is that when running a localnode, the node does only produce new blocks when transactions come in. So when you deploy contract and there is no transaction, timestamps gets not updated.

I deployed contract on Rococo test network, and work just fine.